# jQuery autoellipsis plugin - doesn't work when updating the content

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using the following jQuery plugin :
http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/, and in general it works very well.
The problem comes when I need to update the text of the element. One would assume that changing the text of the element and calling the plugin again would perform the same action the initial call performed.

But, as can be seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohoch/PxszR/3/) - it doesn't.

The code is very simple

```
var container = $(".container");
container.text("This is a long text that should have text ellipsis");
//this works fine
container.ellipsis();
      
  $("button").click(function()
   {
      container.text("This is the modified text that should also have ellipsis");
      //this doesn't work
      container.ellipsis();
   });
```

The only way I could make it work is by deleting the data stored on the element, and by this
making the plugin run "from scratch".

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the data stored by autoellipsis: container.data('jqae', null);

```
var container = $(".container");
container.text("This is a long text that should have text ellipsis");
//this works fine
container.ellipsis();

  $("button").click(function()
   {
      container.data('jqae', null);
      container.text("This is the modified text that should also have ellipsis");
      //this doesn't work
      container.ellipsis();
   });
```

Comment: Thanks @Fredrik. But this is exactly what I said in my question - "The only way I could make it work is by deleting the data stored on the element". 
I'm looking for a better idea, something that is supported in the API itself. Thanks anyway.